# net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE in LG webOS TV

Tags: reactjs, webos, lg

I'm trying to render some images from our backend, but while debugging I was getting the following error:

`failed to load resource net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`

Tried to follow some solutions in other questions but didn't have success. The security tab on the console doesn't show anything. HLS works normally.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exact problem.

This seems to be an LG issue with some https certificates (LetsEncript) on all their platform below 4.0 (https://www.lgwebos.com/topic/7866-lg-webos-40-and-below-letsencrypt-root-certificated-expired).

Check if it's your case (does your app work correctly on WebOS 5.0 and above?).

If so, the only solution would be to change the issuer of the certificates of your backend.
I tried with a dummy api on a Cloudflare certificate and it worked.